# Implementing extendible hash table in javascript: how to use binary number as index

Tags: javascript, binary, hashtable

I'm studying data structures and trying to implement extendible hashing from scratch in Javascript and I'm confused. Here is an example I'm using as reference [hash table with binary labels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5QIP.png)

Example: to store "john":35 in a table of size: 8 indexes / depth 3 (last 3 digits of binary hash)

1. "john" gets converted to a hash, example: 13,
2. 13 is converted to a binary: 1101
3. find which index of the table 1101 belongs to, by looking at the last 3 digits "101"

This is where I'm stuck. Am I suppose to convert 101 back to decimal form (which would be 5), to then access the index by doing array[5]? Is there a way to label the array indexes in binary format like array[101] (but then wouldn't it be better to use an object?)? This seems like a lot of unnecessary extra steps to avoid just using modulo (13%8), am I missing something? Is this implementation useful in not-javascript language?

First post - thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Internally, all data in the computer is stored in binary, so you can't "convert" from decimal to binary since everything is already binary (it's just shown to use as decimal). If you want to print out a number as binary for debugging purposes, you can do:

```
console.log((5).toString(2)); // will print "101"
```

The `.toString(2)` method converts the number to a string with the binary representation of the number.

You can also write numbers in binary by starting it with `0b`:

```
let x = 0b1101; // == 13
```

If you want to get the last few binary digits of a number, use the modulo operator to 2 to the power of the number of digits you want:

```
(0b1101 % (2**3)).toString(2) // "101"
```

With the table selected, you probably want to use the rest of the number that you haven't used already as the index in the table. We can use the bitshift operator, `>>`, to do this:

```
(0b1101 >> 3).toString(2) // "1", right three bits cut off
```

With a longer number:

```
// Note that underscores don't mean anything, they are just used for spacing
(0b1101_1101 >> 3).toString(2) // "11011" you can see that the right three bits have been cut off
```

Keep in mind that you probably shouldn't be using `.toString(2)` to actually store anything in the table; it should only be used for debugging.

Comment: Thank you, that simplified some of my code. To clarify - in the image the professor is labeling the indices of the table in binary format for theoretical purposes? To actually access array['101'], one would still just use array[5]?

Comment: Yes, I believe so (though take my word for a grain of salt, I'm not in your class). If you really wanted to you could write `array[0b101]`, which the computer would read as `array[5]`